# eval function doen't work fine in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

As far as I know the eval function lets a python program run python code within itself.

I want to run a `print()` command using `eval` function in **Python2.7**, but I received the following error :

```
>>> print "test"
test
>>> command='print "test"'
>>> command
'print "test"'
>>> eval(command)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module>
    eval(command)
  File "<string>", line 1
    print "test"
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Note that I don't have any problem with this command it **python3.4** :

```
>>> print ("test")
test
>>> command='print("test")'
>>> command
'print("test")'
>>> eval(command)
test
>>>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Python 2 [`print xxx`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#print) is a statement, not an expression. [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) is for evaluating expressions; you can use [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#exec) for executing statements.

In Python 3, [`print(xxx)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) is a function call, so it can be evaluated.